# Powershell Text Manipulation

Tags: regex, powershell

I am trying to produce a groomed text file.  Using a utility I was able to produce a listing of good and bad media files.  I'd like to extract a list of the bad media files so I can work on replacing them.

In the log the bad media file looks like this.

```
Testing L:\MUSIC\--Finnegan's Wake.mp3...
First frame invalid
MPEG 2.0 Layer I, 16000 hz, Stereo, Crc: No, Length: 0:00
Invalid bytes at end: 4622724
Frames: 0
Errors: 1 (100.00%)
-- NOT OK --
```

Good files look like this in the log.

```
Testing L:\MUSIC\80's Giga Hits Collection. Only Best Disco Hits (2013) - SMG\1383. William Pitt - City Lights (Extended).mp3...
ID3v1 found: City Lights (Extended) (William Pitt / Euro Disco 80's)
ID3v2 found: 73205 Bytes
MPEG 1.0 Layer III, 320 kbit, 44100 hz, Stereo, Crc: No, Length: 5:10
Frames: 11831
-- Ok --
```

I'm trying to extract on the term `-- Not Ok --`

Using the ps command

```
(Get-Content "c:\working\MP3Test.log") -notmatch "-- Not Ok --" | Out-File "c:\working\Bad.txt"
```

Its still returning all of the songs but just without the `-- Ok --`

I'd like to end up with the just the songs titles that are `--Not Ok--`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you'll probably need a script to do this, because you need to match the LAST line, but you need to write the first line of the block. This seems to work pretty well.

```
$curFile="";

foreach ($line in gc c:\working\MP3Test.log){
    if ($line.StartsWith("Testing ")){
        $curFile = $line.Replace("Testing ","")     
    }
    elseif ($line.StartsWith("-- NOT OK --")){
        Write-Output $curFile
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks,I am having a problem getting the context to output to text using |out-file the file gets created but its blank?

Comment: Ah, yeah. I had Write-Host instead of Write-Output, which is needed if you want to pipe the output. Probably should have had that first anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You need to pipe the output of Get-Content into a where cmdlet like so:

```
Get-Content 'c:\working\MP3Test.log' | ? {$_ -notmatch '-- Not Ok --'} | Out-File 'c:\working\Bad.txt'
```

Better still use the Select-String cmdlet as it will be faster:

```
Select-String  'c:\working\MP3Test.log' -Pattern '-- Not Ok --' | Select -ExpandProperty line | Out-File 'c:\working\Bad.txt'
```

Comment: Dave thanks for your answer.. but using your select-string example, how do I grab the 6 lines above the -- Not Ok-- pattern in the output file?  I need to be able to get the titles.

Comment: For your select-string example I recommend using `-SimpleMatch` since you are not using regex. `-context 6,0` should help with the other requirement.

Comment: Use the `-context` parameter. It takes two numbers one is the number of lines before and the second is the number of lines after. So to get the 3 previous lines and one after: `Select-String  'c:\working\MP3Test.log' -Pattern '-- Not Ok --' -context 3, 1`

Answer (score 0):

[Select-Sting](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh849903.aspx) would be the way to go for this. Specifically the `-Context` parameter

> Captures the specified number of lines before and after the line with the match.

```
select-string "C:\temp\test.txt"  -Pattern "-- NOT OK --" -SimpleMatch -Context 6,0).Context.Precontext
```

That would return the 6 lines before the match. Using at least PowerShell 3.0 we get just the raw text from the MatchInfo object using `.Context.Precontext`.

If there is more that one match  in the file you might have some more post processing.

`Select-String` supports regex which we are *not* using here. To be sure that you don't get unexpected matches in the future you can using `-SimpleMatch`. NOte that it is not required for this specific instance.

To match just the song from that block we can do a little post-processing

```
$result = (select-string C:\temp\test.txt  -Pattern "-- NOT OK --" -SimpleMatch -Context 6,0).Context.Precontext 
$result | where-object{$_ -match "Testing"} | ForEach-Object{$_ -replace "^testing (.*?)\.*$",'$1'}
```

Of the lines that are matched we take the one that matches "Testing". Then, using regex, we remove the testing prefix and the trailing periods. Not the only way to do it of course.